# Python Beautiful Soup and urllib.request - How to get past Steam age check

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, steam, urllib3

I'm trying to make a Steam parser that gets information from the week-long deals.

However, some items are blocked by the age check. I'm using urllib.request and Beautiful Soup 4 to get the information but as you may have guessed, I can't get to the M rated items. I tried searching up similar questions but none show me how to get past the age check using urllib.request

I want test to equal 'No description' only when the item actually has no description

Here's my code:

```
import urllib.request

import bs4 as bs

source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=weeklongdeals')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

searchResultContainer = soup.find('div',{'id':'search_result_container'})
containerHolder = searchResultContainer.findChildren()[1]

links = []
for a in containerHolder.findAll('a', href=True):
    links.append(a['href'])

x = 0
description = []
for link in links:
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(str(link))
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

    try: 
        test = soup.find('div',{'class':'game_description_snippet'}).get_text().strip()
        description.append(soup.find('div',{'class':'game_description_snippet'}).get_text().strip())
    except:
        test = 'No description'
        description.append('No description')
    finally:
        x += 1
        print(f'{x}: {test}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure age selection is saved in a cookie, so you'll need to save that cookie and use it for your session.

I would generally recommend using [requests](https://3.python-requests.org/user/quickstart/#cookies) for ease of use, should make this quick and painless.